# Setting up Gmail subdomain on my domain

Tags: google, subdomain, google-workspace, gmail

I just set up my domain with Google Apps. During the Gmail setup process the tutorial said we could also set up `mail.mydomain.com` and we'd look at it later. But it never came up.

Now, I can't seem to find how to do it anywhere. Maybe I just don't know how exactly to search for it.

Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a [CNAME record pointing to ghs.google.com](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53340) and enable the url in your apps control panel.

This works for all services e.g. mail. sites. docs. etc

Comment: Cool... are you the only one besides me on this site :-) So I guess the problem was I was searching for gmail subdomain where I should have been search for apps subdomain or the less techie create a custom web address. Thanks.

Comment: @SaadFarooq it does feel that way some days! I think most of our users are US based. No worries.

Comment: SaadFarooq and toomanyairmiles you are not alone :-) @toomanyairmiles how do I "enable the url in [my] apps control panel"?

Comment: @MartinDuys it's in settings > email (or docs or whatever) > change url

Answer (score 3):

This has changed.

As of sep-2014:
The CNAME target should be: ghs.googlehosted.com
And you enable the URLs from dashboard -> Company Profile > Custom URLs

[Google's support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53340?hl=en)